# What's the proper way to enable fact storage in Ansible Automation Platform?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-automation-platform

I need to enable fact (variable) storage so that a fact stored in one job template is available in a following job template in a workflow. Here's what my job templates look like:

Job template #1: Set Fact

- Enable Fact Storage: checked
- Playbook: `set_fact_playbook.yml`

`set_fact_playbook.yml`:

```yaml
---
- name: Set fact
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Assign my_variable
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        my_variable: My variable content
        cacheable: yes
```

Job template #2: Get Fact

- Enable Fact Storage: checked
- Playbook: `get_fact_playbook.yml`

`get_fact_playbook.yml`:

```yaml
---
- name: Get fact
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: my_variable

    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: ansible_facts['my_variable']
```

Job template #2 (Get Fact) runs "On Success" after job template #1 (Set Fact) in the workflow. Here's the result of Get Fact:

```
TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] ***************************************************
task path: /runner/project/ansible/get_fact_playbook.yml:7
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_variable": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'my_variable' is undefined. 'my_variable' is undefined"
}

TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] ***************************************************
task path: /runner/project/ansible/get_fact_playbook.yml:10
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts['my_variable']": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'dict object' has no attribute 'my_variable'. 'dict object' has no attribute 'my_variable'"
}
```

I also tried enabling fact storage in `ansible.cfg`:

```ini
[defaults]
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/ansible_cache
fact_caching_prefix = ''
fact_caching_timeout = 86400
```

I stored the `ansible.cfg` at the root of the repository from which the project syncs, in accordance with [this documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/tipsandtricks.html#locate-and-configure-the-ansible-configuration-file:%7E:text=place%20it%20at%20the%20root%20of%20your%20project). I've verified that AAP can see this file with a `stat` task, resulting in:

```json
"stat": {
  "exists": true,
  "path": "/runner/project/ansible.cfg",
```

I even found [this Red Hat KB solution](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6968832) which states that the AAP must be configured for the UTC time zone, which mine is.

At this point I don't know what else I need to do to enable fact storage. What am I doing wrong and what's the right way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

"Fact caching is always enabled" cf https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html

i think the only way for you to keep vars is to write them down in a yml/json file and read them

you can use the copy module or the template module to write a file. https://www.ansiblepilot.com/articles/write-a-variable-to-a-file-ansible-module-copy-vs-template/

then, to retreive them you can use :

```
# Get fact
- hosts: localhost 
  vars_files: vars.yml
  tasks:
    - ...
```